# Host SvelteKit project in Microsoft IIS

Tags: javascript, iis, svelte, vite

I've been trying to deploy a svelte application into an IIS server my company has provided. I've tried using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-adapter-iis) adapter, but i couldn't manage to make it work.

Should I keep on trying on maybe suggest some other solution, like express?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the application have backend logic? If not, you don't need any of that.

Comment: It does, it needs to handle a couple of API endpoints.

Comment: You should be more specific in how it does not work then. Also, if using IIS is not a strict requirement, I would not bother with it.

Comment: I'll try and push on changing the hosting solution then. Thanks for your help

Comment: This link may help you: [https://dev.to/wearahelmet/deploying-svelte-app-to-iis-1kia](https://dev.to/wearahelmet/deploying-svelte-app-to-iis-1kia).

Answer (score 3):

## Deploying Sveltekit App IIS

### Building App

Sveltekit apps being deployed on IIS need to be built using adapter node

- `npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-node`

After install open svelte.config and change top line to use adapter-node: `import adapter from @sveltejs/adapter-node';`

Inside your svelte.config make sure to use this node

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    },
    preprocess: vitePreprocess()
};

export default config;
```

Build app: `npm run build`

### Deploying on server

> Node and IISNode must be installed on server

#### Set up site url

1. Create physical path for built in `C:\inetpub\projectname\wwroot`
2. Add index.html inside of root with boilerplate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

3. Add site:

   - Open IIS Manager
   - Click on Server Name -> Sites
   - Right click on sites -> Add Website
   - Give it a name and host name (web address sitedomain)

- Physical path inetpub -> wwroot

4. Add write permissions for site

   - Right click on project folder(inetpub->projectfolder) -> Properties -> secutiry -> edit -> add
   - Click on locations
   - Select server at top of location window -> Click OK
   - In the object names box add the site name (you can see it in the IIS Manager if you forget)
   - Click Check Names
   - The site name should be added and underlined if entered correctly
   - Click OK
   - In Permissions box click on site name -> Allow write permissions -> OK

#### Test URL

On local pc go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc -> host add ip and webaddress`

- add domain to host file

  - 10.39.2.50        sitedomain

Navigate to http://sitedomain
Should see boilerplate html

#### Add build to server

Add build folder inside project wwwroot folder

Inside your build folder you need to add two files.

server.cjs file:

```
process.env.SOCKET_PATH = process.env.PORT;
delete process.env.PORT

import('./index.js')
```

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.cjs" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <iisnode
            nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;"
            watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;*.cjs" 
        />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                <rule name="node">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.cjs" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
          <!-- Change it back if Location Header got rewrited-->
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="back">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="(.*)/server.cjs" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
        </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="server.cjs" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- Copy build files to server build folder
- Copy package.json, packagelock.json, and .env(if there is one) into build folder

### Install packages

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. Cd into build folder
3. Run `npm ci --omit dev`

### Prisma apps

If you are using prisma you will need to copy the .prisma folder from local pc node-modules into server node-modules. Also if you have more than one database connection you will need to copy each generated prisma node `@generated-db`

### Change Site location

After all of these steps are completed go back into IIS Manager and click on the new site -> basic settings and change the physical path from wwwroot to build folder.

Comment: Our site is running on IIS https://test.secureship.ca:8081/ But for some reason the `event.getClientAddress()` method returns undefined. Any thoughts? You can see the output that I returned on the console.

Comment: Thanks for the above info. It took me some time to set up. Everything is working as expected. However, it seems like the `.env` variables are not loading automatically. I have installed `dotenv` on the project but don't know how to run this command `node -r dotenv/config build` to load them automatically. Or just copying the .env file would be enough here?

Comment: I copy the .env file into the build directory and it works for me as long as I install dotenv. As far as the event.getCliendAddress() I don't have any suggestions sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble finding this when I was looking so I thought I’d put it here for anyone else looking.

The easiest way now is to use something like
https://github.com/abaga129/sveltekit-adapter-iis to automatically create the node server and web config for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).